# Triggering event continuously when Button is pressed down in Android

Tags: android

I have `Button` and an `TextView`. Initially on click of button i an incrementing the count value and display in the TextView. The code i have used to do so is.

```
buttonDayPlus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{               
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) 
     {
     count = count + 1;
         textView.setText(Integer.toString(count));
     }
}
```

But now what i want is if the user pressed the Button, then i want to increment the value one after another and display the increment value in the `textView` and as soon as user move his hand up...the final increment value is shown in `textView`. So if anyone knows help me to solve this out

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553163/android-long-touch-event

Answer (score 8):

You will need to use a Handler object because you have to implement a separate thread for incrementing/decrementing

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private boolean autoIncrement = false;
    private boolean autoDecrement = false;
    private final long REPEAT_DELAY = 50;
    private Handler repeatUpdateHandler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.input);

        class RepetitiveUpdater implements Runnable {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (autoIncrement) {
                    increment();
                    repeatUpdateHandler.postDelayed(new RepetitiveUpdater(), REPEAT_DELAY);
                } else if (autoDecrement) {
                    decrement();
                    repeatUpdateHandler.postDelayed(new RepetitiveUpdater(), REPEAT_DELAY);
                }
            }

        }

        up.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                increment();
            }
        });

        up.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                autoIncrement = true;
                repeatUpdateHandler.post(new RepetitiveUpdater());
                return false;
            }
        });

        up.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && autoIncrement) {
                    autoIncrement = false;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    public void increment() {
        if (i < 100) {
            i++;
            TextView no = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.no);
            no.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        }

    }

}
```

Do the same for decrement.

Courtesy: Github, author: Jeffrey F. Cole

Answer (score 4):

I just answered this question here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41466381/2991628

I created a `CounterHandler` class to do all the counting and event handling. This is how it works.

```
 new CounterHandler.Builder()
            .incrementalView(buttonPlus)
            .decrementalView(buttonMinus)
            .minRange(-50) // cant go any less than -50
            .maxRange(50) // cant go any further than 50
            .isCycle(true) // 49,50,-50,-49 and so on
            .counterDelay(200) // speed of counter
            .counterStep(2)  // steps e.g. 0,2,4,6...
            .listener(this) // to listen counter results and show them in app
            .build();
```

You can find this class from my gist 
https://gist.github.com/nomanr/d142f4ccaf55ceba22e7f7122b55b9b6

Answer (score 2):

You should use [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) instead of OnClickListener.

However, your question is ambiguous. If you want to increment the value only once when the button is released you would do something like this:

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            count++;
        }
    }
};
```

If you want to increase count while the user is holding down the button you would do it like this:

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        count++;
        myTextView.setText("Click count: "+count);
    }
};
```

Where myTextView of course is the textview you want to show the clicks on.

Comment: But in my case i have to show the user the change in the count value in textview as long as user presses the button. I mean to say How would I have the count value increment/decrement and show in textview if the button is held?

Comment: Why is your boolean not returning any value @EmirKuljanin?

Answer (score 0):

Use custom touch listener like this,

```
public class CustomTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {     
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    switch(motionEvent.getAction()){            
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
           count = count + 1;
                break;          
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:             
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
          textView.setText(Integer.toString(count));
                break;
    } 
        return false;   
    } 
}
```

and set these listener to your button. May it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

As @shalini gave answer is right but there are little change as per your requirement is

```
public class CustomTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {     
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    switch(motionEvent.getAction()){            
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
               count = count + 1;
               textView.setText(Integer.toString(count));
            break;          

           case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:             

           case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                break;
    } 
        return false;   
    } 
}
```