# how to increment a value continuosly when a button is pressed?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a button and a textview with the number 1 displayed when my app is running. When i press and hold the button i want the value to continuosly increment till I let go of the button. It is very frustrating for me because i used to know how to do this and it was as simple as setting the button properties to something in xml. However I have forgotten how and i have searched through the internet and the examples i have found implement an ontouch listener that only increments the value by one. But i want the value to be increment continuosly depending on how long the user presses the button. this is not a repeat of 
[Triggering event continuously when Button is pressed down in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12071090/triggering-event-continuously-when-button-is-pressed-down-in-android)

[Triggering event continuously when Button is pressed down in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12071090/triggering-event-continuously-when-button-is-pressed-down-in-android)

as they did not work for me. so can some remind me how to get a button to increment a value continuosly when you press and hold the button?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://spleenware.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/auto-repeat-buttons-in-android.html

Comment: Give a try to the OnLongClickListener interface!

Answer (score 0):

Use onTouchListener and start/stop your counter routine on MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN and MotionEvent.ACTION_UP

Answer (score 0):

[Android long-touch event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553163/android-long-touch-event)

bramburys answer in the link above worked perfectly whilst other answers incremented one at a time when the button was pressed whilst bramburys incremented continuously.