# How do i increase the value of a textview with a handler? (or other solution)

Tags: android, handler, android-handler

first of all, i already tried this: [Continuously increase integer value as the button is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938516/continuously-increase-integer-value-as-the-button-is-pressed)

But i had 59 errors, yep, 59, and as i used to use Eclipse which told you CLEARLY what kind of error you had, how to fix it, and Android Studio looks that was made for people with experience... I can't even understand what the hell to do, to fix all errors (btw, when i try to fix something i break 10 more somehow).

So... Given a Button and a TextView how do i do to increase the textview (like a Clicker game for example) and make it stop pressing the same button again:
And how do i put the intervals between each "click"

```
TextView score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
score.setText(Integer.toString(i));

    Button click =   (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    click.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            i++;
            score.setText(Integer.toString(i));

        }
    });
```

By the way... I don't need the solution, i need to understand how exactly Thread or Handlers works, yes everybody will recommend me the Documentation, but i need to see a SIMPLE example explained part by part and i will understand way more than i already do by reading the documentation.

Comment: Start with the first error. What is it? What line of code causes it?

Comment: "when i try to fix something i break 10 more somehow" this is a common experience for all programmers, even the most experienced of us

Comment: "i need to understand how exactly Thread or Handlers works" Threads are used for take which take a long time to finish, such as reading a file or downloading an image. Handlers are for communicating between threads. You do not need either of these to accomplish the task at hand.

Comment: Refer back to my first comment and [edit] your question to show what errors you get. Solving compiler errors is part of the learning process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Given a Button and a TextView how do i do to increase the textview (like a Clicker game for example) and make it stop pressing the same button again: And how do i put the intervals between each "click"

Given your `score` and `click` widgets from your question:

Step #1: Add a `Runnable` field to your activity or fragment. Here, I'll call it `incrementer`.

Step #2: Define a `static final int DELAY` field in your activity or fragment, with the delay period you want ("intervals") in milliseconds.

Step #3: Have your `Button` use `postDelayed()` and `removeCallbacks()`, based on the state of `incrementer`:

```
click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(final View v) {
    if (incrementer==null) {
      incrementer=new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          i++;
          score.setText(Integer.toString(i));
          v.postDelayed(incrementer, DELAY);
        }
      };
      incrementer.run();
    }
    else {
      v.removeCallbacks(incrementer);
      incrementer=null;
    }
  }
}
```

The `incrementer` field serves two roles. It tracks whether we are incrementing the `TextView` content or not, and it is the actual code that does the incrementing.

If `incrementer` is `null`, we are not presently incrementing the `TextView`. So, we assign `incrementer` a `Runnable` that can increment the `TextView`. The `Runnable` also calls `postDelayed()` to say "hey, run this `Runnable` again after `DELAY` milliseconds". We `run()` the `Runnable` ourselves the first time, to both populate the `TextView` at the outset and to trigger the `postDelayed()` call to schedule the next increment.

That will then continue to "loop" (`run()` calling `postDelayed()`, scheduling a future call to `run()`) until the user clicks the button again. Then, we see that `incrementer` is *not* `null`, so we must be incrementing the `TextView` and need to stop. `removeCallbacks()` unschedules the last `postDelayed()` call, stopping the "loop". We set `incrementer` to `null` mostly to prepare ourselves for the next button click.

Comment: Sorry for the late "Correct Answer" tick :D
And thanks for the explanation.